# Theming Module Output

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

What I am trying to do is generate some raw output within a module.

I would like to pass an array of data through to a template file, and then use that data to populate the code from the template. The template is represented by a file in my theme folder.

I have a hook set up for a certain URL (/itunes):

```
$items['itunes'] = array(
    'page callback'     =>  'itunespromo_buildpage',
    'type'              =>  MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
    'access arguments'  =>  array('access content'),
);
```

..inside itunespromo_buildpage...

```
function itunespromo_buildpage() {
    //grab some data to pass through to template file, put into $promo_data
    $details = theme('itunes_page', array(
        'promo_data'    =>   $promo_data,
    ));
    return $details;
}
```

Here is the hook_theme():

```
function itunespromo_theme() {
    return array(
        'itunes_page'   =>  array(
            'template'  =>  'itunes_page',
        ),
    );
}
```

Inside my theme's template.php:

```
function geddystyle_itunes_page($vars) {
    return print_r($vars['promo_data'], true);
}
```

Right now, $promo_data *is* being passed through fine, and it is print_r'd on to the result page. However, I'd like to then take this $promo_data variable and use it in my itunes_page.tpl.php template file.

I'm kind of certain I'm close here. Am I supposed to call some sort of render function and pass the $promo_data variable to it from function itunespromo_theme()?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to update your hook_theme() to provide the ability to send variables to your template file.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function itunespromo_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
 return array(
  'itunes_page'   =>  array(
    'variables' => array(
      'promo_data' => NULL,
      ),
      'template' => 'itunes_page',
    )
  );
}
```

Also, instead of calling the theme() function directly what you want to be doing is actually constructing a renderable array and letting Drupal call the theme() function. What you should be doing is calling drupal_render which in turn calls theme() for you. Look at this piece of advice here for a little more clarity:

http://drupal.org/node/1351674#comment-5288046

In your case you would change your function itunespromo_buildpage to look something like this:

```
function itunespromo_buildpage() {
  //grab some data to pass through to template file, put into $promo_data
  $output = array(
  '#theme' => 'itunes_page',
  '#promo_data' => $promo_data //call $promo_data from the tpl.php page to access the variable
  );
  $details = drupal_render($output);
  return $details;
}
```

Comment: Wow.. that worked perfectly. Thank you so much, you have no idea how much hair I've pulled out of my head today. I've basically put on 30 years as far as hair loss goes.

Comment: Woops, spoke a little soon.. given these changes, how can I access the $promo_data variable from within itunes_page.tpl.php.

Comment: Given the code there $promo_data was in $options. (Declared in $output as #options - just change #options to #promo_data and that should work) I've changed it to reflect what you should do.